# 100 Gold coins, and a bunch of pirates

Tags: logical-deduction

A group of Five pirates (It's a small crew, ok?) have obtained 100 gold coins and have to divide up the loot. The pirates are all extremely intelligent, and tend to be total butts to each other (especially the captain).

The captain always proposes a distribution of the loot. All pirates vote on the proposal, and if half the crew or more go "Aye", the loot is divided as proposed, as no pirate would be willing to take on the captain without superior force on their side.

If the captain fails to obtain support of at least half his crew (which includes himself), he faces a mutiny, and all pirates will turn against him and make him walk the plank. The pirates start over again with the next senior pirate as captain.

What is the maximum number of coins the captain can keep without risking his life?

Comment: I will add a hint in...... 24 hours.

Comment: I know this one... I won't answer it now... Cause it would be fast. :)

Comment: @Lasoloz OK. Well, I'll be waiting :)

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling! This is a common question - I highly recommend making your own puzzles instead of posting ones you've found somewhere else.

Comment: @f'' Its a lot simpler than that... Mess. I prefer puzzles that someone can solve if they put effort in, but not sit there and physically draw/write up a bleeping spreadsheet to explain the answer. Besides, I want a definitive figure here, no equation.

Comment: @Deusovi You sure? See my comment to F. Also, I did search this beforehand, and could not find any similar questions(No offense)

Comment: @Dan: Yes, it's the same puzzle. The answer there is just very formal.

Comment: @Deusovi Alrighty then :)